# Directshow advice for range of functionality or is there a better alternative (.NET)?

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I've been doing some work in VB.Net with Directshow over the past 3-4 weeks. I'm creating an application to keep tags on a video and eventually want to be able to extract the tagged parts of the video to a new file. In a video that is 2 hours long I might want to extract say 50 10-15 second "clips" up to 15 times (event tagging). This will be for a free application.

I've found it brilliant (and easy) to render / seek / play clips, etc on XP-Win7 with no issues. I've "discovered" the joys of GraphEdit, creating graphs, the issues with COM in VB.NET, GMFBridge, ....etc.

Now I need some advice. Am I using the right technology. Directshow seems to be very resistant to the idea of "open video", "seek to clip", "write clip to file", .....repeat for all clips, close file. I can sort of do this already if I visibly render the video but would need to do it as a background task faster than realtime render speed.

Things that seem to be missing are:
 - an example of anyone doing anything similar (export multiple clips to a single file)
 - no easily available 64bit compressors (lots of 32bit stuff around)
 - all the references and examples I do find are VERY old
 - VB.NET is not the first "port of call" for DirectShow developers

So, the question is, should I be using something else?

If not, has anyone done anything similar before. I'm not looking for their code, I just want some guidelines as it takes ages to figure things out in DirectShow and VB.Net just using trial & error (and Google).

I've looked at AFORGE (no sound), FFMPEG (command line toolset), Media Foundation (reluctant to throw away XP) and a variety of commercial helper libraries but not really getting any further.

Apologies for the length but I wanted readers to understand the background.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To output clips to a single file Microsoft had created the "[DirectShow Editing Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". Sometimes it works, sometimes not. We use it in our software to create videos from clips like you. With a little bit work you can also include effects to the video.

It is also possible to use [AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page). It's a scripting system and frameserver for DirectShow.

As I know, with MediaFoundation you can also create a video from [multiple clips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I never tried this.